# How do I fix the AWS Wild Rydes sample error: InvalidParameterException: "username should be an email"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, sample

Following the AWS WildRydes sample to [Build a Serverless Web Application](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito), after setting up the Cognito User Pool any attempt to register a user on the sample website generates the error:

```
 InvalidParameterException: Username should be an email
```

The username I am using is a valid email (my genuine email address).  The error is being returned from the Cognito service.  Google turns up nothing obvious.  I have followed the sample carefully.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems obvious that Cognito is attempting to validate the username passed and finding that it is not a valid email address, despite me supplying a valid email.  Cognito is unlikely to be buggy, so I dug into the sample code supplied by AWS.  In the `js/cognito-auth.js` file I found that where the username parameter is being passed to Cognito it is wrapped in a `toUsername()` function:

```
userPool.signUp(toUsername(email), password, [attributeEmail], null,
```

The function replaces the @ in the email with -at-:

```
function toUsername(email) {
    return email.replace('@', '-at-');
}
```

I took the quick way out and updated the toUsername() function:

```
function toUsername(email) {
    return email;
}
```

After pushing the change to CodeCommit and waiting for Amplify to deploy it, my registration and Sign in works.  The sample code I changed was straight from AWS, so I'm not sure how this crept in, could be:

1. I made a mistake with the user pool setup, though I was pretty careful and it's all the defaults
2. Something has changed with the default setup of a User Pool
3. Cognito has added validation forcing the user name to be a email.

Anyway, I'm posting this to assist if others experience it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Peter already does an extremely good job of answering the question.

An alternative solution is also removing the function call toUsername(email)

BEFORE:

```
userPool.signUp(email, password, [attributeEmail], null,
```

AFTER:

```
userPool.signUp(toUsername(email), password, [attributeEmail], null,
```